# Lubuntu wi-fi driver installation with no wired connection

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, lubuntu

I'm going to install Lubuntu on my parent's old PC (AMD 2200+ 1.8GHz, 1GB RAM, GeForce FX 5200) because new Linux Mint doesn't work with this GPU :(

I tried the LiveCD and it does not look as good as Mint, but it should be ok for my parents. The only problem is that it doesn't detect any wi-fi networks so I will have to install the driver from the Internet; however, I can't wire this old PC to router which is on the other floor (don't ask if maybe I can move PC/router, no way).

How can use my laptop to get the proper drivers (.deb package?), then copy and install on PC?

Wi-fi card is Ralink 3060.

Comment: what's the wifi cards model number? `sudo lshw -c network` once you get correct driver just move it from laptop to PC on a flash drive, or burn on cd

Comment: I believe this device should work by default. Please also show us: rfkill list all Thanks.